# ¿Como tener un Recycler View con items de distintos tamaños en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

**Descripción:**

Básicamente tengo un recycler view que muestra ítems de height="100dp" y otros items de height=
"120dp". El problema está en que al deslizar el recycler (al reciclar las vistas), los items con height="120dp" se comprimen hasta tener 100dp para igualar al resto.

**Pregunta:**

¿Cómo puedo lograr que mi recycler no comprima las vistas para poder lograr tener items de distintos tamaños?

¿Hay alguna propiedad de recycler view que solucione esto?

**Gracias por leer!**

Comment: Según lo que sé, RecyclerView está pensado para el rendimiento, para lograr su cometido usa un mismo diseño para todos los elementos y reemplaza los datos por los correspondientes. Deberías explorar los diferentes `LayoutManager`s existentes o considerar crear uno propio para lograr tu cometido.

Comment: Intenta buscar un diseño consistente, si quieres la misma apariencia, deja siempre un mismo tamaño para todas las celdas y adapta el contenido.  Si resulta que el diseño es diferente, tienes que emplear dos ViewHolder, el cual cada uno controlará una vista diferente.

Answer (score 0):

El Adapter tiene un propiedad que te puede ayudar mucho `getItemViewType()`, Esta propiedad devuelve un valor entero que puedes tomar como un tipo, por ejemplo imaginemos que devolvemos mediante esta función el número [1] entonces el Adapter entiende que el layout será de tipo [1], imaginemos que devolvemos el valor [2] entonces el Adapter entiende que estamos trabajando con el tipo [2]. Para un mejor detalle te invito a visitar el siguiente enlace donde tienen un ejemplo completo de como usar esta propiedad.

https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/07/03/recyclerview-multiples-vistas-viewholders-android/

En este ejemplo se tiene:

```
private final int TIPO_NORMAL = 1;
private final int TIPO_VER_MAS = 0;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  if (position == listaDeGastos.size() - 1) return TIPO_VER_MAS;
  return TIPO_NORMAL;
}
```

Lo que esta pasando es  lo siguiente: Cuando se tiene la última posición del `listadoDeGastos` se devuelve el entero `TIPO_VER_MAS` en cualquier otro caso se devuelve `TIPO_NORMAL`, en tu caso esta función debería devolver la lógica para saber cuando devolver un tipo de 120dp y otro tipo de 100dp.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case TIPO_VER_MAS:
            View filaVerMas = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fila_ver_mas, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolderVerMas(filaVerMas);
        case TIPO_NORMAL:
        default:
            View filaGasto = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fila_gasto, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolderGasto(filaGasto);
    }
}
```

Ahora en tu RecyclerView.ViewHolder podemos utilizar esta propiedad para inflar varios tipos de layout ( en tu caso por ejemplo podrías utiliza el tipo `TIPO_NORMAL` para llamar a un layout que tenga deán height de 120dp y podrías utilizar el tipo `TIPO_VER_MAS` para inflar un layout de 100dp.